# Appendix Title with scrreprt

Tags: chapters

I'm trying to get the word Appendix in front of my appendix chapter titles. I would like it to look like:

Appendix A  My first appendix

I tried the appendix package, using \usepackage[title,titletoc]{appendix}. Somehow this works in the toc but not in the title on the page itself. How can add it for the title as well?

Here what I got:

```
\documentclass[pdftex,parskip=half,twoside, BCOR15mm]{scrreprt}%
\usepackage[title,titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, fancyhdr}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{here}


\begin{document}


\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter 1}
\chapter{Chapter 2}


\begin{appendices}


\chapter{Bli bla blubb}


asdasd
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have nothing after the appendices, then this should do (I omitted the irrelevant packages and options). You don't need the `appendix` package.

```
\documentclass[
  appendixprefix=true, % the title will have Appendix A
]{scrreprt}

\makeatletter
%% change \numberline so that it will print "Appendix A"
\newcommand\appendix@numberline[1]{\appendixname\ #1\autodot\ }
\g@addto@macro\appendix{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{
    \let\protect\numberline\protect\appendix@numberline}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter 1}
\chapter{Chapter 2}

\appendix
\chapter{Bli bla blubb}

asdasd

\end{document}
```

### Table of contents

[image]

### Appendix

[image]

---

Notes.

1. Don't add the `pdftex` option. It's not needed and may cause problems.
2. Don't load the `here` package. It's obsolete and actually loads `float`. The `[H]` option to `figure` or `table` only makes typesetting worse.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works perfectly well. Thanks for the hints too, I always thought I might have some unnecessary stuff included.